# How does async works in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

Microsoft announced the [Visual Studio Async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx) today (October 28, 2010) that introduces the `async` and `await` keywords into C#/VB for asynchronous method execution.

First I thought that the compiler translates the keywords into the creation of a thread but according to the [white paper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=d7ccfefa-123a-40e5-8ed5-8d2edd68acf4&displaylang=en) and Anders Hejlsberg's [PDC presentation](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/1b127a7d-300e-4385-af8e-ac747fee677a) (at 31:00) the asynchronous operation happens completely on the main thread.

How can I have an operation executed in parallel on the same thread? How is it technically possible and to what is the feature actually translated in IL?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It works similarly to the `yield return` keyword in C# 2.0.

An asynchronous method is not actually an ordinary sequential method. It is compiled into a state machine (an object) with some state (local variables are turned into fields of the object). Each block of code between two uses of `await` is one "step" of the state machine.

This means that when the method starts, it just runs the first step and then the state machine returns and schedules some work to be done - when the work is done, it will run the next step of the state machine. For example this code:

```
async Task Demo() { 
  var v1 = foo();
  var v2 = await bar();
  more(v1, v2);
}
```

Would be translated to something like:

```
class _Demo {
  int _v1, _v2;
  int _state = 0; 
  Task<int> _await1;
  public void Step() {
    switch(this._state) {
    case 0: 
      this._v1 = foo();
      this._await1 = bar();
      // When the async operation completes, it will call this method
      this._state = 1;
      op.SetContinuation(Step);
    case 1:
      this._v2 = this._await1.Result; // Get the result of the operation
      more(this._v1, this._v2);
  }
}
```

The important part is that it just uses the `SetContinuation` method to specify that when the operation completes, it should call the `Step` method again (and the method knows that it should run the second bit of the original code using the `_state` field). You can easily imagine that the `SetContinuation` would be something like `btn.Click += Step`, which would run completely on a single thread.

The asynchronous programming model in C# is very close to F# asynchronous workflows (in fact, it is essentially the same thing, aside from some technical details), and writing reactive single-threaded GUI applications using `async` is quite an interesting area - at least I think so - see for example [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Programming-user-interfaces-using-f-sharp-workflows.aspx) (maybe I should write a C# version now :-)).

The translation is similar to iterators (and `yield return`) and in fact, it was possible to use iterators to implement asynchronous programming in C# earlier. I wrote [an article about that](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async.aspx) a while ago - and I think it can still give you some insight on how the translation works.

Answer (score 51):

> How can I have an operation executed in parallel on the same thread?

You can't. **Asynchrony is not "parallelism" or "concurrency"**. Asynchrony might be implemented with parallelism, or it might not be. It might be implemented by breaking up the work into small chunks, putting each chunk of work on a queue, and then executing each chunk of work whenever the thread happens to be not doing anything else.

I've got a whole series of articles on my blog about how all this stuff works; the one directly germane to this question will probably go up Thursday of next week.  Watch [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151102210456/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/async/) for details.

Answer (score 8):

As I understand it, what the `async` and `await` keywords do is that every time an `async` method employs the `await` keyword, the compiler will turn the remainder of the method into a continuation that is scheduled when the async operation is completed. That allows `async` methods to return to the caller immediately and resume work when the async part is done.

According to the available papers there are a lot details to it, but unless I am mistaken, that is the gist of it.

As I see it the purpose of the async methods is not to run a lot of code in parallel, but to chop up async methods into a number of small chunks, that can be called as needed. The key point is that the compiler will handle all the complex wiring of callbacks using tasks/continuations. This not only reduces complexity, but allows async method to be written more or less like traditional synchronous code.

Comment: How is it scheduled without a separate thread? Is a continuation a specific concept in the CLR that allows some light-weight scheduling?

Comment: @0xA3: I believe the paper says that the async method doesn't run on it's own thread. I.e. just like TPL it will be a mix of the current thread and thread pool threads depending on the situation.