# How does Task<int> become an int?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

We have this method:

```
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{ 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

   Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

   // You can do work here that doesn't rely on the string from GetStringAsync.
   DoIndependentWork();

   string urlContents = await getStringTask;
   //The thing is that this returns an int to a method that has a return type of Task<int>
   return urlContents.Length;
}
```

Does an implicit conversion occur between `Task<int>` and `int`? If not, then what is happening?  How is it implemented to work?

Comment: [Keep reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh524395.aspx).  I assume the compiler takes care of that based on the `async` keyword.

Comment: @Freeman, Look at this great explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4047607/280758

Answer (score 234, accepted):

> Does an implicit conversion occur between Task<> and int?

Nope. This is just part of how `async`/`await` works.

Any method declared as `async` has to have a return type of:

- `void` (avoid if possible)
- `Task` (no result beyond notification of completion/failure)
- `Task<T>` (for a logical result of type `T` in an async manner)

The compiler does all the appropriate wrapping. The point is that you're *asynchronously* returning `urlContents.Length` - you can't make the method just return `int`, as the actual method will return when it hits the first `await` expression which hasn't already completed. So instead, it returns a `Task<int>` which will complete when the async method itself completes.

Note that `await` does the opposite - it *unwraps* a `Task<T>` to a `T` value, which is how this line works:

```
string urlContents = await getStringTask;
```

... but of course it unwraps it asynchronously, whereas just using `Result` would block until the task had completed. (`await` can unwrap other types which implement the awaitable pattern, but `Task<T>` is the one you're likely to use most often.)

This dual wrapping/unwrapping is what allows async to be so composable. For example, I could write another async method which calls yours and doubles the result:

```
public async Task<int> AccessTheWebAndDoubleAsync()
{
    var task = AccessTheWebAsync();
    int result = await task;
    return result * 2;
}
```

(Or simply `return await AccessTheWebAsync() * 2;` of course.)

Comment: can any details be offered for how it works under the hood, just curious.

Comment: +1 Good answer as always. And why are you so pretty fast writing them?!

Comment: +1: Just started looking into `async`/`await` and I find this extremely non-intuitive. IMO, there should be a keyword or similar at the `return` to make this clear, e.g. `return async result;` (in the same way that `await result` "unwraps" the `T` from the `Tast<T>`).

Comment: @dav_i: The difference is that without the `await`, the expression would still make sense - whereas `return` is unambiguous. It may be a bit more of a pain the first time you use it, but I think once you're used to it you'll be glad there isn't the extra fluff.

Comment: @JonSkeet But it doesn't make sense without the `await` - with `T foo = someTaskT;` you'd get "Cannot implicitly convert type `Task<T>` to `T`" - in the same way I argue that it would make more sense to have a keyword for the inverse (wrapping in `Task<T>`). I'm all for removing fluff but in this case I think it provides an unnecessary obfuscation within `async` methods. (Obviously the point is moot because the powers that be have already spoken/coded!)

Comment: @dav_i: The *assignment* doesn't make sense, but the rest does. And there are cases where the whole statement would make sense - although it might not be useful. Given that the method is already declared `async`, I think that's enough.

Comment: @JonSkeet both of the links in your comment seem to be broken now. Can we have them updated if possible? Thanks.

Comment: @akka16: The Tekpub screencast series is now on Pluralsight. For Eduasync, you want https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/eduasync/

Comment: It's good to know Author of C# in Depth is active here.

Comment: What's the point of using `await` instead of `.Result` in an asynchronous method B if the caller method A awaits the method B right away?, i.e. without doing any work between calling B and awaiting B.

Comment: @PedroMachado: If the task hasn't immediately completed, method B will "pause" (without consuming a thread) rather than blocking until the task has completed.

Answer (score 18):

No requires converting the Task to int. Simply Use The Task Result.

```
int taskResult = AccessTheWebAndDouble().Result;

public async Task<int> AccessTheWebAndDouble()
{
    int task = AccessTheWeb();
    return task;
}
```

It will return the value if available otherwise it return 0.

Comment: that is not what i asked.

Comment: This does not answer the question. But more importantly, **this is very bad advice**.  You should almost *never* use `Result`; it can cause deadlocks! Consider for example this workflow: (1) Write a note that says "mow the lawn". (2) Wait for the lawn to be mowed (3) Eat a sandwich, (4) Do whatever it says on the note".  With that workflow, you never eat a sandwich or mow the lawn, because step 2 is a *synchronous wait* on something that you will do *in the future*.  But that's the workflow that you are describing here.

Comment: @EricLippert: Not clear your example. Can you please explain how Result can introduce deadlocks when await won't?

Comment: Await means to do something while you're waiting for the result and that something can include doing work to compute the result. But synchronous waits do nothing while you wait which means you could be preventing the work from being done.

Comment: @EricLippert. Will this have the same issue ? 'Task.Run(()=> AccessTheWebAndDouble()).Result;'

Comment: .Result can block and is generally considered a very bad idea. I can't believe this has any upvotes let alone 22.