# using await and Task.Result in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, async-await, parallel-processing

Hi I am having following web api code which is having multiple async and await methods as shown below

```
[HttpPost("test/id")]
public async Task TestWebMethod(int id)
{               
  bool TestA = await _Service.GetAsyncMethodA(id);
  if (TestA)
   {
     bool TestB = await _Service.GetAsyncMethodB(id);
     await _Service.GetAsyncMethodC(TestB);
   }            
}

public async Task<bool> GetAsyncMethodA(int id)
{
   // do something
}

public async Task<bool> GetAsyncMethodB(int id)
{
   // do something
}
```

If we want to use the result from the first async method to be passed to the second method this implementation will work?  or should i use **Result** keyword as shown below?

```
public async Task TestWebMethod(int id)
{               
  bool TestA = _Service.GetAsyncMethodA(id).Result;
  if (TestA)
   {
    bool TestB = await _Service.GetAsyncMethodB(id).Result;
    await _Service.GetAsyncMethodB(TestB);
   }            
}
```

Which is the correct approach in the above scenario ? with **await** keyword or use the **Result** keyword?
Please suggest.

Comment: Is this question related? [Await vs Task.Result in an Async Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239661/await-vs-task-result-in-an-async-method)

Answer (score 2):

you need to fix the code. You can not use await and .Result together. You have to use something one. It is much better to use await

```
public async Task TestWebMethod(int id)
{               
  bool testA =  await _service.GetAsyncMethodA(id);
  if (testA)
   {
   var testB = await _service.GetAsyncMethodB(id);
    await _service.GetAsyncMethodB(testB);
   }            
}
```