# Correct way to use async await with AcquireTokenForClient().ExecuteAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, token

I am new to the async await method in C#.
I have a function called InitServiceAsync I am new to the async await method in C# which will init the service and get the tokens for this client
because `AcquireTokenForClient(s).ExecuteAsync()` is an async funtion so I use await to wait for authentication data

Then I assign the `task.Result` return from `InitServiceAsync()` to `_service`
Will it cause dead lock? Can anyone suggest what is the right way to call `AcquireTokenForClient` with async/await correctly?
Thanks

```
void fun(){
    Task<ExchangeService> task = InitServiceAsync();
    _service = task.Result;
}
```

```
private static async Task<ExchangeService> InitServiceAsync()
       {
           ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1, tzi);
           var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                   .Create(appId)
                   .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                   .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                   .Build();
           var s = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };
           var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(s).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
           service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
           return service;
       }
```

Comment: Where are you calling it from? Is it a constructor? Please post the entirec caller method

Comment: Hi @CodeNameJack I have modified the code hope it wil be clear. There is a funtion foo then I want to init service in foo()

Answer (score 3):

if you use `task.Result` you will wait for the execution of the `async` task which will make it more or less synchronous again.

```
ExchangeService exchangeService = await InitServiceAsync();
_service = exchangeService;
```

I'm also no expert, there are plenty other devs which will explain it to you better, but thats the way i would handle it :)

> The only difference is that the await will not block. Instead, it will
> asynchronously wait for the Task to complete and then resume

Check here [Await vs Task.Result in an Async Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239661/await-vs-task-result-in-an-async-method)

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of Asynchronous Main, I don't think much is left to call an asynchronous Method in a synchronous context.

I would suggest you do,

```
async Task fun()
{
    _service =await InitServiceAsync();
}
```

If this code is part of a constructor, then, I would suggest you initialize it first and then inject the initialized version in constructor.

At last, if you are building a library, and want to provide synchronous version of async code, then you can refer to these answers. Suggest you go through at least 3-4 answers before making your decision.
[How to call asynchronous method in sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Comment: I used this code but got an error like Cannot implicitly convert type from Task<ExchangeService> to ExchangeService when using ```_service =await InitServiceAsync();``` Is there any suggestion for solve this problem? Thanks!!

Comment: With `await` you should not be getting the error, This happens if you don't use the `await` keyword. Type of _service should be `ExchanegService`. Post the exact error if you face this issue.