# How do I cancel a Task that I didn't create?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, cancellation-token, cancellationtokensource

I have a Task returned from a third party.  It does not give me the option to insert a cancellation token when constructing the task.  Can I insert a cancellation token into a task after the fact?

Something like this:

```
Task thirdPartyTask = ThirdParty.GetTask();
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
thirdPartyTask.SetCancellationToken(cts.Token);
var result = await thirdPartyTask;
cts.Cancel();
```

I am aware the normal way is to insert the cancellation token during construction, but I do not have access to that, since it is third party.

[I am forced to use the `await` keyword, because I am in Unity.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660049/how-do-i-avoid-async-void)

I want to cancel the task in a non-cooperative fashion.  I want to abort/kill the task against its will.

How can I cancel a task that I didn't create?

Comment: dont think you can add one after its made

Comment: What would you like the `CancellationToken` to do? Would you like it to cancel the asynchronous operation in a non-cooperative fashion, or you are satisfied with just cancelling the *awaiting* of the operation? In the second case your code would stop awaiting the operation, but the operation itself would keep going in the background. Hint: don't ask for the first if you are satisfied with the second. The first might require much more work from you to do. Please consider editing the question and specifying your preference.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I don't think I understand your question.  I want to cancel the task in the same way as though I inserted a CancellationToken during construction.  For the task to stop and throw an error.

Comment: So you want to cancel the task in a non-cooperative fashion. In other words you want to abort or kill it against its own will. Please include this requirement in the question. It is important information for answering it.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias done, thanks!

Comment: I added [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77229683/how-to-cancel-a-task-without-passing-a-cancellationtokensource-in-net) as duplicate. I hope that you are able to isolate the asynchronous operation in a separate process so that you can kill it, and I also hope that killing the process will not corrupt the overall state of you application (considering as state also the filesystem, database etc that your application depends on). Having parts of your application fighting against other parts, is never going to be pretty.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I already reviewed those, which don't work for me because I am using a third party library in Unity :( Which is why I do not believe this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Another relevant question, which is about canceling synchronous methods: [Thread or Task (stopping a hung single line of code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75087774/thread-or-task-stopping-a-hung-single-line-of-code).

Comment: I have very limited knowledge about the Unity engine, but I will be surprised if there is a solution to this problem that works for Unity and doesn't work for all other application types in .NET. My understanding is that non-cooperative cancellation is a fundamentally hard and nasty problem. It means that you are stuck with using a bad library, and you have no other option than using force to make it behave in a way that it was never designed to behave.

Comment: Btw if anyone knows an answer to this question, that is specific for Unity applications and it would be off-topic if posted as an answer to the linked questions, please tag me in a comment and I'll cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias IF the question asked about a specific method in a specific library in a specific situation, an isolated solution could theoretically exist, but that's not what's being asked  It's asking about any method in any library (that happens to be called from a unity application) .  That the method is called from a unity application changes nothing about the nature of the problem, which is strictly identical to the duplicate (calling an arbitrary method from an arbitrary library).

Comment: @Servy sure. But if someone knows of a solution that is specific for Unity applications, then the question could be edited (specialized) accordingly. I find it highly unlikely to happen, but you never know.