# How to implement Stop/Cancel async operations in WinForms application when I can't pass token to async method?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

I have asynchronious WinForms application that uses

1. async/await event handlers of buttons
2. objects with asynchronous method from another assembly that I can't modify.

I want

1. to disable elements while operation is performing so I need to implement callback functions or just enable elements in Stop button
2. and I want' to have button that stop performing operation.

```
private async void buttonCheckProxy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ProxySource src = (ProxySource)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProxySource), comboBoxSource.SelectedValue.ToString());
        Protocol prot = (Protocol)Enum.Parse(typeof(Protocol), comboBoxProtocol.SelectedValue.ToString());
        CheckType checkType = (CheckType)Enum.Parse(typeof(CheckType), comboBoxCheckType.SelectedValue.ToString());

        if (checkType == CheckType.WebRequest)
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            await _proxyChecker.CheckAllWebRequestAsync(src, prot);
            MessageBox.Show("Completed");
        }
        else
        {
            await _proxyChecker.CheckAllWebBrowser(src, prot);
            MessageBox.Show("Completed");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

How I can make it for my purpose?

Before I used cancellation token but now I don't see how I can use it because I can't pass token to this function:

```
await _proxyChecker.CheckAllWebRequestAsync(src, prot);
```

**Clarification:** I want to kill the asynchronous `CheckAllWebRequestAsync`.

Comment: You'd write better code if you removed all of the `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }` in your code and used the debugger instead to help make your code more robust.

Comment: Unless you have cooperative cancellation then you can't cancel the calls.

Comment: What would you like the `CancellationToken` to do? Would you like it to cancel/kill/abort the asynchronous `CheckAllWebRequestAsync` operation in a non-cooperative fashion, or you are satisfied with just cancelling the *awaiting* of the operation? In the second case your code would stop awaiting the operation and would proceed with doing other things, but the operation itself would keep going in the background.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I want to kill asynchronous CheckAllWebRequestAsync

Comment: Cancellation is something then has to be implemented. If not you cannot cancel. It is that simple. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44545953/1744164). If you have the source of `ProxyChecker` you could implement that or run the check inside of a different process which you can easily kill.

Comment: If the method does not support cooperative cancellation you could run it in a separate process that can be killed, see [What is wrong with thread.abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort)

Comment: A recent question on the same theme (non-cooperative cancellation): [How do I cancel a Task that I didn't create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77304429/how-do-i-cancel-a-task-that-i-didnt-create)

Comment: As a side note, you could simplify the error handling by attaching an event handler on the event [`Application.ThreadException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception), instead of including a `try/catch` block in each and every event handler of your WinForms application. This provided that showing just a message with the error `MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())`, without any other contextual information, is OK.

Comment: @JonasH the `Thread.Abort` is not even remotely an option here, because async methods typically [don't run on threads](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html "There is no thread"). An async method might represent a query on a remote server, the completion of a child-process, whatever. There is no guarantee that this 'whatever' will stop, even if you kill the current process or unplug the PC from the power supply.

Comment: You can't kill `CheckAllWebRequestAsync`, you can only stop awaiting it. You can use [Task.WaitAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync?view=net-7.0) to do this easily. Stephen Toub explains the difference and why cancellation isn't practical in [How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/).

Comment: If your service has a cancellation call, eg a `StopJob(id)` or `Disconnect` or whatever,  you can use [CancellationToken.Register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register?view=net-7.0) to call if if cancellation is requested

Comment: What is `_proxyChecker` and what does `CheckAllWebRequestAsync` do? If this starts another program eg `curl` and you keep track of the started processes, you could call `Process.Stop` to stop this. If you use Selenium or Playwright you can terminate the browser or Playwright/Selenium service. If you use Selenium Grid, you can make an API request to cancel the job