# Why isn't a CancellationToken included in the Task<T> monad?

Tags: c#, f#, task-parallel-library, async-await, monads

`Task<T>` neatly holds a "has started, might be finished" computation, which can be composed with other tasks, mapped with functions, etc. In contrast, the F# [`async`](http://tomasp.net/blog/async-csharp-differences.aspx/) monad holds a "could start later, might be running now" computation, *along with* a `CancellationToken`. In C#, you typically have to thread the `CancellationToken` through every function that works with a `Task`. Why did the C# team elect to wrap the computation in the `Task` monad, but not the `CancellationToken`?

Comment: In C#, you have the *"could start later, might be running now" computation, along with a CancellationToken* option in the form of `var task = new Task(action, token)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More or less, they encapsulated the implicit use of `CancellationToken` for C# `async` methods. Consider this:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.Cancel();
var token = cts.token;

var task1 = new Task(() => token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested());
task1.Start();
task1.Wait(); // task in Faulted state

var task2 = new Task(() => token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), token);
task2.Start();
task2.Wait(); // task in Cancelled state

var task3 = (new Func<Task>(async() => token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()))();
task3.Wait(); // task in Cancelled state
```

For a non-async lambda, I had to explicitly associate `token` with the `task2` for cancellation to propagate correctly, by providing it as an argument to `new Task()` (or `Task.Run`). For an `async` lambda used with `task3`, it happens automatically as a part of `async/await` infrastructure code.

Moreover, *any* `token` would propagate cancellation for an `async` method, while for non-async computational `new Task()`/`Task.Run` lambda it has to be the *same* token passed to the task constructor or `Task.Run`.

Of course, we still have to call `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` manually to implement the cooperative cancellation pattern. I can't answer why C# and TPL teams decided to implement it this way, but I guess they aimed to not over-complicate the syntax of `async/await` yet keep it flexible enough.

As to F#, I haven't looked at the generated IL code of the asynchronous workflow, illustrated in Tomas Petricek's [blog post](http://tomasp.net/blog/async-csharp-differences.aspx/) you linked. Yet, as far as I understand, the token is automatically tested only at certain locations of the workflow, those corresponding to `await` in C# (by analogy, we might be calling `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` manually after every `await` in C#). This means that any CPU-bound work still won't be cancelled immediately. Otherwise, F# would have to emit `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` after every IL instruction, which would be quite a substantial overhead.

Comment: When and why would you want to use async/await for CPU-bound work?

Comment: @GregC, anytime I need to do CPU-bound work in a UI app: `var pi = await Task.Run(() => CalcPi(digits, token), token)`.

Comment: @GregC As a form of parallelization. `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`.

Comment: I know what it is that most people want to do with async/await.  It's meant for monadic injection of functionality, similar to IEnumerable.  It makes continuation-passing style look procedural, at the expense of additional orchestration.  As such, I wouldn't use it in places where you wouldn't use CPS.

Comment: @GregC, I'd rather compare `IEnumerable` to `IObservable` (a feature of Rx, as opposed to TPL's `Task`).

Comment: I'd like to link an exceptional explanation by Thomas P http://stackoverflow.com/a/15615804/90475

Answer (score 2):

Task was initially made to contain additional features in the class, but later was changed to aggregate an object with additional feature support.  All in the name of performance.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235962.aspx (see "restructuring Task" in the paper)  The paper by Joseph E. Hoag gives nice insights into optimizations done in .NET 4.5.  I believe it would be a worthwhile read for anyone trying to squeeze the last 10% of performance out of async/await.

I assume a similar thought process was applied when deciding how to package cancellation functionality.

I can't speak for C# or [BCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library#Base_Class_Library) team, but I assume it's a performance optimization that's either only possible in F# compiler, or performance was immaterial to F# team. [SRP, baby!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: I'd forgotten about that Hoag paper. Seem like the drive was to keep the Task object itself as small as possible, hence not carrying around the Cancellation token, but instead carrying it around in the state machine generated by async/await.