# Is it possible for the compiler to create async code that would have a StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, async-await, c#-5.0

Referenced Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4047607/347172

---

Basically, since the compiler is creating a state machine that uses recursion, is it possible that a class that has "*too many*" `await`s will cause the compiler to generate code that will throw an exception?

Comment: If you're asking if it's possible that the compiler generated state machine can run into a StackOverflowException, I would say it's possible because it's software but very very unlikely.
Why are you asking?

Comment: @PauloMorgado: To get a better understanding of how async/await works, and what it's limitations are.

Comment: OK. But I'm still wondering why this specific question. You're not if it's reentrant (which it isn't), you're asking if it's flawed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in the way you're thinking. The compiler creates a state machine that will *schedule* itself, not *call* itself. The scheduling creates a "trampoline" which resets the stack.