# Blazor-Wasm: Why does `await Task` blocks UI, but `await`-`async` doesn't?

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm currently trying to call asynchronously an expensive method in blazor WASM while not blocking the UI thread.

According to answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864285/blazor-ui-freeze-even-when-task-is-used), it is impossible. However, these date back to a couple of years ago, and according to the [WebAssembly roadmap](https://webassembly.org/roadmap/), threading is supported by modern browsers.

Also, I can `await` function calls without blocking the UI thread, as long as the functions are awaitable from the bottom up.

In the following code snippet, clicking the `Foo` button will cause the UI to hang for a couple of seconds while the operation is carried out, but clicking the `Bar` button will process a similar (but awaitable) operation in the background while keeping the UI responsive.

If WebAssembly doesn't support multi-threading, why does the second option seem to work with multiple threads? If it does support multi-threading, why does the first option block the UI?

```
@page "/asynctest"

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        @DisplayValue
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <button type="button" @onclick="OnClickFoo">Foo</button>
    </div> 
    <div class="col">
        <button type="button" @onclick="OnClickBar">Bar</button>
    </div> 
</div>

@code{
    private string DisplayValue = "";
    private double Result;
    private async Task OnClickFoo(EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayValue = "Working...";
        Result = await Task.Run(() => Frobnicate()); // Blocks UI thread
        DisplayValue = Result.ToString();
    }
    private async Task OnClickBar(EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayValue = "Working...";
        Result = await FrobnicateAsync(); // Doesn't block UI thread
        DisplayValue = Result.ToString();
    }
    private int Frobnicate()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000); // do some heavy work
        return 42;
    }
    private async Task<int> FrobnicateAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000); // do some heavy work async
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fildor I tried, it doesn't make any difference on the UI blocking, the only effect is that the UI isn't updated upon completion, requiring to call `StateHasChanged()` manually.

Comment: Try this: `Result = await Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(1); return Frobnicate(); });`

Comment: @Fildor - do **not** use async void in Blazor. You don't need them, you don't want them.

Comment: @HenkHolterman OK. Is that a "speciality" of Blazor? Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Yes, more or less. Blazor Events will adapt to a Task return type and await it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I am aware, Blazor WASM does not support multithreading, you only get 1 thread.

In the "OnClickBar" method, you are not creating a different thread. You are using the async/await state machine which returns control to the calling thread. The `Task.Delay(2000)` does not block the thread as seen in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246237/does-task-delay-waste-system-resources-while-it-is-waiting#:%7E:text=Delay(1000)%20doesn%27t,block%20the%20thread%2C%20unlike%20Task.)

In the "OnClickFoo" method, you are calling Task.Run which does try to create a background thread - this does not work properly in WASM as you have a single thread, so when you call `Thread.Sleep(2000);` - it is the UI thread that is sleeping.

More info on threading here: [Microsoft Docs - Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model#:%7E:text=The%20async%20and%20await%20keywords%20don%27t%20cause%20additional%20threads,You%20can%20use%20Task.)

Related Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864285/blazor-ui-freeze-even-when-task-is-used)

Comment: This is correct.  Multi-Threading WASM is on the roadmap, but when ...????.  `Thread.Sleep` is blocking and blocks the only thread available.

Comment: Exactly, threads are supposed to be introduced in .net 7, but it is not yet in the current preview https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-7-preview-2/.  Also See this thread https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17730