# runsettings.xml file not working with dotnet test coverage command

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, code-coverage

I am trying to generate coverage report for one of my project using following commands:

```
dotnet test "testproject.csproj" /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=\"cobertura,lcov\" /p:CoverletOutput="D:\coverage" --settings "runsettings.Runsettings"
```

I have given following settings in my runsettings.Runsettings file:

```
       <CodeCoverage>
         <ModulePaths>
          <Include>
            <ModulePath>.*WCController.dll</ModulePath>
          </Include>
         </ModulePaths>
        <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->
         <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>False</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
         <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
         <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
         <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>
      </CodeCoverage>
```

but when I run this command it is displaying [image]

As you can see that I specified only to include *WCController.dll assembly but still it is showing coverage of other assemblies as well.

Please help me find the exact reason of this issue beacuse I don't want any other assembly in my coverage report.

Answer (score 1):

you can add an "exclude" block after your "include."  Something like this:

```xml
<ModulePaths>
  <Include>
     <ModulePath>.*WCController.dll</ModulePath>
  </Include>
  <Exclude>
     <ModulePath>.*WCController.*.dll</ModulePath>
     <ModulePath>.*WCControllerTests.*.dll</ModulePath>
     ...
  </Exclude>
</ModulePaths>
```