# Difference between await and myTask.Result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

When you call an async method, it returns a `Task<T>`, where `T` is the type of the result.

Now, you've got two ways to deal with this task. You can either use the getter `.Result` to wait for the task to finish and get the wrapped value, or you can use `await`, which looks like it's doing the same thing. Or isn't it?

I tried to find an answer for this question and saw @Frank Fajardo [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32239717/21566347) saying this:

> await asynchronously unwraps the result of your task [...] Result would block [...]

I'm not entirely sure what @Frank Fajardo is saying. Doesn't `await` also block the execution of `Main()`?

Here is an example: note that `foo()` is only called **after** the task returned by `barAsync()` is completed (when using `await barAsync()`).

The same is true for `fooTask().Result` and `barAsync().Result`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class App
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (await barAsync());
        Console.WriteLine (foo());
        
        Console.WriteLine (fooTask().Result);
        Console.WriteLine (foo());
        
        Console.WriteLine (barAsync().Result);
        Console.WriteLine (foo());
    }
    
    public static Task<string> fooTask()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
           return "faz";
        });
    }
    
    public static async Task<string> barAsync()
    {
       Thread.Sleep(5000);
       return "baz";
    }
    
    public static string foo()
    {
       return "--- faz ---";
    }
}
```

So, what's the difference? Which thread isn't blocked when using `await`?

Comment: I recommend [Stephen Cleary's series of blog posts](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html) on that exact topic.

Comment: More specifically, [this post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html).  It explains why calling `.Result` instead of awaiting can deadlock your code.

Comment: The main thing to grasp, I think, is that blocking is different from continuing a sequential control flow. No matter if it's async I/O or just another thread (potentially) taking over (or not).

Comment: Do I miss something? He's also "just" saying: '[...] await will asynchronously wait (not block) [...]'. What does "block" mean in this context? For me, it seems like await IS blocking :/ @RobertHarvey, I must have misunderstood something, but I can't get behind it.

Comment: Could you show me a simple example that demonstrates the difference? @Fildor

Comment: The difference is huge. `.Result` blocks the calling thread until the task completes. In a desktop application, that freezes the UI. In a web application, a threadpool thread is blocked and can't serve other requests. When you use `await` though the calling thread is released until the task completes. That means the UI remains responsive, and the request thread is released to process other requests. When the task completes, execution is resumed in the original "synchronization context". In a desktop app, that means execution is resumed on the UI thread.

Comment: On a web app, execution is resumed on another threadpool thread but uses the original HTTP request context (including the request/response objects, the controller instance etc). On a busy web server that means significantly fewer threads and less CPU can be used to handle the same traffic

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Perhaps my misconception is related to threads and "blocking." I thought that my Main() method runs on one thread, and the `Thread.Sleep(1000); return "faz";` and `barAsync` run on their own threads. I also believed that using `.Result` and `await` would block the thread of my `Main()` method. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: await and .Result would block the Thread Main() runs on*

Comment: No. `await` doesn't block the main thread. Only `.Result` does. Your code has no UI or other request to process though, so it appears it's blocked. Try the same thing in a WinForms or WPF application and notice what happens if you call `.Result` in an event handler. You won't be able to click or type anything.  If you move the form around you'll notice that the form isn't even redrawn if the UI thread is frozen

Comment: In my example is there more than one Thread? Is the thread that is calling await blocked until the task is complete? Does .Result alway block the main thread even when called from a different one? @PanagiotisKanavos And Thanks alot for your help!!!

Comment: Ufff... : https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: Ok. So, it's exactly the problem I was mentioning above. The thing is: there are actually two different things abstracted away in the async/await Task Syntax: Cpu bound tasks and I/O bound tasks. That doesn't make it easier to understand. The "there is no thread" refers to the I/O part. While (the program flow is) waiting for external I/O, the thread is free to do other things (= not blocked). So,  YOU are waiting, but there is no thread sitting around doing nothing.  And that's the easy part. If the task is performing Cpu-Bound work, it _may_ still execute synchronously...

Comment: It may also be freed and another thread picks up... and when it finally returns, "it depends" on context if the original thread needs to continue or just any thread can.

Comment: Now if you look at it from the perspective of the thread, it executes your code ... until it hits an await. Then it executes some other code until it is free again and your code ready to be picked up. Then it executes your code again. If you look at it from the perspective of your program, it gets executed until the await is hit, then for a while nothing happens, until finally it's going on with the result. So it looks blocked, but it's not. But still the same instructions are executed in the same sequence as if it were. Did that make sense?

Comment: @Fildor *"Then it executes some other code until it is free again"* -- What other code?

Comment: @Servy there is nothing in this question related with deadlocks. The [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock) is related, but not duplicate. Could you link to another question that is actually a duplicate of this question?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, Fildor could you check my answere? Did I understand it correctly?
And Thanks again for all your Help!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That *is* a duplicate.  The question is asking about the difference between synchronously blocking and awaiting, which is the same as this question.  That there's the word "deadlock" in there doesn't change that.  It just contains a better example in it's question about why they're different than this one does.  You do realize that *asking identical questions* don't cease to become duplicates just because one contains a word that the other doesn't, don't you?

Comment: @Servy this question is not identical with the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock). That's my opinion, and my vote represents my opinion. I am pretty sure that duplicate questions exist, but I don't have time to search. If you find one, please post the link in the comments.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Your assertion that questions need to be identical to be duplicates is false.  I understand that you *wish* anything that's not a copy paste, even if it's a single word off, makes it not a duplicate but that's not how this site works.  The answers answer the question, and the differences don't change what the answer is.  In what way to you feel the answers fail to answer the question asked?

Comment: @Servy the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock) asks *"What could cause this deadlock?"*, and contains three off-topic answers that doesn't answer the question asked. Anyway, it's not important to convince me. You have presented your arguments, and any member with the privilege to cast [reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) can evaluate your arguments and vote accordingly. That's how this site works.

Comment: Why is this a down voted Question? Can anyone explain to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's what I discovered and grasped:

As explained by @Tomas Petricek [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4047607/21566347), a method marked as `async` is compiled into a state machine with multiple steps. Each `await` keyword indicates a new step.

When the function is called, the first step is executed, which sets some state of the state machine (usually the local variables used in the method). A call to the awaiter of the awaitable object (the object behind the await keyword) is then made.

Upon completion of the awaitable object (often a `Task<T>` or `Task`), the next step of the state machine is called. This involves obtaining the result of the awaitable object and setting it in the state machine's member as part of its state.

Because this state machine lifes only in the RAM and is neither garbage collected nor tied to any thread, the next step can be called from any other thread. This results in:

> "So, YOU are waiting, but there is no thread sitting around doing
> nothing," as described by @Fildor.

On the other hand, Wait and .Result will block the thread they are called from until the task completes.

So, as @Fildor mentioned:

When you call `.Result`, a thread is waiting for the completion of the task. On the other hand, when using await, the next part of the method is called after the task has completed. This doesn't block a thread, but it can pause the sequence (your method).

cf.

> Now if you look at it from the perspective of the thread, it executes
> your code ... until it hits an await. Then it executes some other code
> until it is free again and your code ready to be picked up. Then it
> executes your code again

Comment: For those interested in delving deeper, I discovered a YouTube series that appears promising: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqJESGHEMDY.

I've just begun watching the first part, and it seems to be a good and easily understandable resource.

Answer (score 2):

The `.Wait()` blocks the current thread until the task completes. The `await` doesn't block the current thread. Instead the current execution flow (the `async` method) is suspended, and when the task completes the flow is resumed on the thread that completed the task. In most cases the completing thread is a `ThreadPool` thread. The completing thread is chosen by the internal implementation of the asynchronous method.

Some application types, like WinForms and WPF applications, are equipped with an app-specific [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext) on the main thread ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext)). This is a scheduler that alters the behavior of every `await` by rescheduling the `await` continuation, usually redirecting it back on the UI thread.

Console applications are not equipped with a `SynchronizationContext` (and no specialized built-in implementation exists for them). Since the termination of the main thread results in the termination of the process, Console applications with `async` [`Main`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#async-main-return-values) method actually block the main thread, to prevent the process from terminating. The blocking is performed with the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, which is similar with the `.Wait`, differing only on how the exceptions are propagated.